# Two sided test: proc ttest?

Tags: sas

I need to calculate the two-sided ttest in SAS.
I generally use the proc ttest adding side=2 but I am not sure if this test works fine or if another way should be preferred to it.

An example of data is the following:

```
Score Segment Obs Class_obs 
1      0      500  15
1      1      500  34
2      0      234  23
2      1      766  65
```

Where the p-value is calculated per each score. Segment means that a condition is met (e.g. score higher than 60. 0 means ‘lower than 60’ while 1 means ‘higher than 60’).
Obs is the number of observations in each segment by score. Class obs is the number of obs that satisfy a specific condition on the overall population.

Happy to share more info if it needs.

Comment: What is your null hypotheses?

Comment: @whymath, the null hypothesis is no difference in Class obs across the scores. The difference can be positive, negative and also changing the sign across scores. Passing criteria is p>0.05

Comment: You should share your code, but your test seems a bit more like Chi Square than T-Test as it's count data.